# The solid border does not work when i hover over it

Tags: css, border, navbar

I wanna apply a border-bottom for the anchor tag of the navbar but it doesn’t work when i hover over it also the color does not change to white

My code

```
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent !important;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s !important;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s !important;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;
}
```

it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AivpM.jpg)

Comment: Your `:hover` and `:active` rules are not applying because the `!important` rule on the links have higher priority.

Comment: Is there a reason than you've had to include the importants - for example another setting further down the styling cascade?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
    background: green;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s !important;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s !important;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

YOu are using !important the wrong way. If I understand correctly, your code should be like:

```
.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22!important;
}
```

And all other `!important` does not need to be added.
Please provide HTML context next time

Comment: I edited the code but it still doesn’t  work